# python: simulating the multiple inheritance of class variables

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, class-variables

I have a class hierarchy where some methods work with a list of properties defined at the class level.

Let's say that for class `A` I have `A.X = [propA1, propA2]` and for subclass `C` I need `C.X = [propA1, propA2, propC]`.  Subclasses inherit the properties from the parents, so it would make sense to write class methods with `super()` calls, each one using the properties of their own class.

However, it is a bit cumbersome. I can deal with all properties in a single method in the base class. So it really feels more natural to define a class variable containing an array of new properties for each subclass and manually go down the `cls.__mro__` to retrieve all properties.

What I've come up with (below) seems to work relatively transparently but is it idiomatic?  Is there a more typical coding pattern for this?  Is there a way to avoid decorating all subclasses?

```
class Base(object):
    pass

class InheritClassVariable:
    def __init__(self, var, base):
        self.var = var
        self.base = base
    def __call__(self, cls):
        name = self.var
        uname = '_' + name
        bases = [B for B in cls.__mro__ if issubclass(B, self.base)]
        setattr(cls, uname, getattr(cls, name, []))
        value = [item for B in bases for item in getattr(B, uname, [])]
        setattr(cls, name, value)
        return cls

@InheritClassVariable('X', Base)
class A(Base):
    X = ['propA1', 'propA2']

@InheritClassVariable('X', Base)
class B(Base):
    X = ['propB']

@InheritClassVariable('X', Base)
class C(A):
    X = ['propC']

@InheritClassVariable('X', Base)
class D(C,B,A):
    X = ['propD']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f"D.X = {D.X}")
```

Comment: I answered something roughly similar by using metaclasses.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62164653/1394353 `habits` there seem equivalent to `X`. Metaclasses are often overkill but can be useful for handling ancestor **class**, not **instance** hierarchies.  Still definitely use cautiously.

Comment: Thank you, I looked up what a metaclass is and could do it in the simple case.  Then I saw that __init_subclass__ was available to avoid subclass and I indeed managed to do it in a much simpler way.

Comment: yes, forgot to mention that.  chepner's answer, if i remember.  that's a new-ish feature, hadn't heard about it until 6 months or so ago.  regardless of how you do it, do be **very** careful with class level mutable attributes like lists.   not saying you shouldnt use them, but you cant let instances mutate them again.  if you need to that, do something like `self.X = self.X.copy()` first.  or `self.X = self.X + [var]`  not  `self.X.append(var)`

Comment: Yes, they are constants. If they were mutable, a `get()` method would make more sense.

By the way the metaclass solution becomes awkward if two hierarchies with their own metaclass cross.

Answer (score 2):

A commentator mentioned metaclasses, something I didn't know of.  I looked it up and found out there is an `__init_subclass__` method that is meant to avoid some of the uses of metaclasses.

That being known, I could simplify my code to (edited):

```
def InheritConstantArray(varname, value=[]):
    """Return a class making the 'varname' array to be inherited in subclasses"""
    basename = f"InheritConstantArray{varname}"

    def init_subclass(cls):

        # it seems __class__ won't work here.  I still don't understand
        # why.  All I know is eval() is dirty so I do a lookup.
        allbases = cls.mro()
        base = [b for b in allbases if b.__name__ == basename][0]

        # collaborate with other classes using __init_subclass__().
        # if we want sevaral variables to be inherited.
        super(base, cls).__init_subclass__()

        # base._X[cls] will store original cls.X
        uvarname = f'_{varname}' if varname[0] != '_' else f'{varname}_'
        if not hasattr(base, uvarname):
            setattr(base, uvarname,  {base: value})
        stored_values = getattr(base, uvarname)
        stored_values[cls] = cls.__dict__.get(varname, [])

        # Then we set cls.X value from base classes
        bases = [b for b in allbases if issubclass(b, base)]
        values = [i for b in bases for i in stored_values.get(b, [])]
        print(cls, base)
        setattr(cls, varname, values)

    dct = {varname: value, '__init_subclass__': init_subclass}
    base = type(basename, (object,), dct)

    return base

class A(InheritConstantArray('X')):
    X = ['A']

class B(A):
    X = ['B']

class C(A):
    X = ['C']

class D(B,C,InheritConstantArray('Y')):
    X = ['D']
    Y = ['d']

class E(D):
    X = ['E']
    Y = ['e']

class F(D):
    X = ['F']
    Y = ['f']

class G(E,F):
    X = ['G']
    Y = ['g']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f"A.X = {A.X}")
    print(f"B.X = {B.X}")
    print(f"C.X = {C.X}")
    print(f"D.X = {D.X} {D.Y}")
    print(f"E.X = {E.X} {E.Y}")
    print(f"F.X = {F.X} {F.Y}")
    print(f"G.X = {G.X} {G.Y}")
```

I'm still unsure if it's the standard way to do it, though. (Yes, there is a very strong rationale to have class variables and multiple inheritance in my real-world problem.)